# How to stop pasted text being highlighted in terminals in Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, clipboard, zsh

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 16.10 from 16.04, every time I paste text into a terminal running `zsh`, that text is highlighted until I type another character. It doesn't seem to matter which terminal emulator I use (it happens both in `gnome-terminal` and `terminator`), all that seems to matter is that `zsh` is the shell (`bash` does not have the problem). How can I prevent this?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot ? I can't reproduce what you're reporting. My pastes aren't highlighted at all, cursor positioned at the end

Comment: I can't reproduce it either on 16.04 (when I paste, the cursor goes to the end and nothing is highlighted)

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. As it turns out, the problem seems to be specific to `zsh`. Will update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally found it (https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/issues/349):

```
# in ~/.zshrc
zle_highlight+=(paste:none)
```

Comment: where should that go? Also the downsides are not clear to me

Comment: OK, found out: should go in `~/.zshrc` (like `setopt interactivecomments` and others)